# PHP Curl connection to an IP without a domain

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a simple POST curl request to an IP without a domain. The response is as shown:

```
Error:Failed to connect to 213.177.9.75 port 9998: Connection refused
```

My code is:

```
        $jud='BC';
        $nr ='22';
        $lit='BAC';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://213.177.9.75:9998/verf_nr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "jud=$jud&nr_id=$nr&lit=$lit&_token=V6O6u3Nl9Fc26VkUqspnQXFB2sXrwbPkYcqD0fYl");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
        $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
        $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
        $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
        $headers[] = 'Origin: http://213.177.9.75:9998';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain';
        $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36';
        $headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
        $headers[] = 'Referer: http://213.177.9.75:9998/';
        $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6';
        $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site';
        $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors';
        $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: font';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Length: 0';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

     print_r($result);
```

It won't connect at all even though through a browser, it all works perfectly. I simply want to get the HTML returned by the redirect of the request above and use DOMDocument on it.

http://213.177.9.75:9998/publica

write BC in 'Judet', 22 in 'Nr.' and BAC in 'AAA' and check network tab for the specific request.

I appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Is this happening on a web hosting site? There's probably a firewall blocking it.

Comment: Many public web hosting services block connections to unusual ports.